# Export to Excel file name

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, gridview, export-to-excel

I wrote this codes for export GridView to Excel :

```
System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.Clear();
Response.Buffer = true;
Response.ClearContent();
Response.ClearHeaders();
Response.Charset = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.EncodingName;
Response.ContentEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
Response.BinaryWrite(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetPreamble());
string FileName = Title + ".xls";
StringWriter strwritter = new StringWriter();
HtmlTextWriter htmltextwrtter = new HtmlTextWriter(strwritter);
Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=" + FileName);
```

but file name does not show correctly for non english names(Such as Arabic). How I can save file with non english names?

[image]

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap file name With

```
Server.UrlEncode
```

for example:

```
string FileName = Server.UrlEncode(Title + ".xls");
```

and it works!!!!